# Hue Hive -- Beeswax Server Can't Find JDBC Driver for MySQL

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue

We're using the Cloudera 3.7.5 and having a tough time configuring the Beeswax server such that the Hue can access the Hive databases.  I followed all the instructions from the Cloudera documentation that to setup MySQL to serve as Hive's metastore, but when I restart the Hue services and check Beeswax server's StdErr logs, I still see the painful "javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory" which is caused by

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "DBCP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
```

This is bizzare to me, because the logs also indicate that the environment variable HIVE_HOME is equal to "/usr/lib/hive", and sure enough I have copied the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar" into the /usr/lib/hive/lib directory, as the documents dictate.

I have also tried the instructions on the blog post http://hadoopchallenges.blogspot.com/2011/03/hue-120-upgrade-and-beeswax.html, which involved copying the the mysql-connector jar into "/usr/share/hue/apps/beeswax/hive/lib/".  Unfortunately I did not have a hive/lib subdirectory in the beeswax folder, so I attempted to make one.  This also did not work.

Any advice how I can get the MySQL JDBC library onto Beeswax's classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally decided to just bite the bullet and `upgrade to CDH4`.  Placing the JDBC jar in `/usr/share/hive/lib` allowed the Beeswax server to function perfectly without issue.

If anyone else is experiencing this issue **I recommend upgrading from CDH3 to CDH4**, the UI is much cleaner, smoother, and we had much fewer installation and maintenance bugs with `CDH4`.

Comment: Under CDH3, the driver jar had to go in /usr/lib/hive/lib (on the beeswax node, obviously, not the Cloudera Manager node)

Answer (score 0):

You have to paste your mysql connector in HUE_HOME/apps/beeswax/hive/lib.
If this path doesn't exist, create hive/lib and then paste the mysql connector. I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: "I have also tried the instructions on the blog post http://hadoopchallenges.blogspot.com/2011/03/hue-120-upgrade-and-beeswax.html, which involved copying the the mysql-connector jar into "/usr/share/hue/apps/beeswax/hive/lib/". Unfortunately I did not have a hive/lib subdirectory in the beeswax folder, so I attempted to make one. This also did not work."

Answer (score 0):

When you start using cloudera 4.5 they move everything into parcels, so this exact problem on my hive meta server was fixed by this command (below). Essentially you're just re-adding modules. I'm sure you can modify the extra classpath in the hive config file to make this oblivious to parcel updates.

```
cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.0-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10/lib/hive/lib/.
```

So a real fix might be something like this:

```
 cp `locate mysql-connector | grep jar | head -n 1` /opt/cloudera/parcels/*/lib/hive/lib/.
```

which would copy the jar into every parcel.